# Disable login from current application php

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication

I have a web application where all the users log in and then they access all other pages of the application. But here I am integrating this application to another application. From that application users are already  logged in.

Here I have a button in other application once user clicks on it, it opens a new window with my application URL, for example `http://phpapplication.com/report1`; here I don't want to show login page once user comes from other application to this application.

How can I disable login in my aplication or do a backend authentication?

Comment: Simple! Check if the user already has authenticated with the other application and if so, pass the details to your application if needed. Please let me know if you need an example.

Comment: That's right can you give an example please

Comment: This question is *very* long way from being answerable. How are sessions maintained in each application? How is authentication implemented? What is the authorization model?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Authentication with PHP, then most likely you could use a pass through function e.g.

```
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$pass = hash("sha256", functionToGetPassFromDBorSESSION());
header("Location: https://myOtherWebApp.com/passthrough.php?user=$user&pass=$pass&redirect=pageToGoTo");
die();
```

the pass though file can then preform automatic authentication and can forward the user to the correct place.

```
AuthenticateUser($_GET['user'],$_GET['pass']); //Password is pre-hashed.
//Authenticate User function will set Session information and authenticate the user.
```